# Rename column data frame sequentially

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this

```
   x           y          z

10             10         0      
00021          21         11    
022            22         1                                         
13610206     13610206     1     
13610207     13610207     1     
13610208     13610208     1     
13610209     13610209     1     
13610210     13610210     1
```

where the second column is y = as.numeric(as.character(x)) and the third is z = diff(y).
What I would like to do is to add a column like this

```
   x           y          z               xnew

10             10         0                10
00021          21         11               00021 
022            22         1                00021                                  
13610206     13610206     13610184         13610206
13610207     13610207     1                13610206
13610208     13610208     1                13610206
13610209     13610209     1                13610206
13610210     13610210     1                13610206
```

i.e. if z=1 xnew is equal to the previous x for which z is different from one.

Comment: I don't understand the question, you have a dataframe with numbers and want to have the difference with the previous number in a second column and then, make a third column where if the difference is less  or equal to 1 you keep the previous number?

Comment: Not the previous number but the last number for which the difference is different from one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the function `na.locf()` ( **l**ast **o**bservation **c**arried **f**orward ) in package `zoo`:

First, import the data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="
x           y          z
10             10         0      
00021          21         11    
022            22         1                                         
13610206     13610206     1     
13610207     13610207     1     
13610208     13610208     1     
13610209     13610209     1     
13610210     13610210     1 ", header=TRUE, colClasses=c("character", "numeric", "numeric"))
```

Next, the analysis

```
library(zoo)

dat$z <- c(0, diff(dat$y))
dat$xnew <- na.locf(ifelse(dat$z==1, NA, dat$x))
dat
```

The results:

```
         x        y        z     xnew
1       10       10        0       10
2    00021       21       11    00021
3      022       22        1    00021
4 13610206 13610206 13610184 13610206
5 13610207 13610207        1 13610206
6 13610208 13610208        1 13610206
7 13610209 13610209        1 13610206
8 13610210 13610210        1 13610206
```

Answer (score 0):

using `apply`:

```
old <- NA
df$xnew <- apply(df, 1, function(row) {
              if (row['z'] != "1")
                old <<- row['x']
              old
            })
df
#          x        y        z     xnew
# 1       10       10        0       10
# 2    00021       21       11    00021
# 3      022       22        1    00021
# 4 13610206 13610206 13610184 13610206
# 5 13610207 13610207        1 13610206
# 6 13610208 13610208        1 13610206
# 7 13610209 13610209        1 13610206
# 8 13610210 13610210        1 13610206
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have this:

```
df
#         x
#1       10
#2    00021
#3      022
#4 13610206
#5 13610207
#6 13610208
#7 13610209
#8 13610210
```

You can convert it to integer by `df[1,]<- as.numeric(df[1,])` And then start to rest the values:

```
z<-0
for (i in 0:nrow(df)){
z<-c(z,df[i+1,]-df[i,])
df<-cbind(df, z)
}
```

But the Andrie solution is better, as it doesn't use the `for` loop, but I wanted to point how to manage the df of string to convert it to number to apply it